# List getListItems WebService SOAP to return folder contents not working

Tags: web-services

It's not working for me, I tried everything and I am really confused:

This is my soap request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName><ListName>Style Library</ListName></listName>
<viewName><ViewName></ViewName></viewName>
<query></query>
<viewFields>
<ViewFields>
</ViewFields>
</viewFields>
<soap12:queryOptions>
<QueryOptions>
<IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
<Folder>http://intranet.go4teams.com/Style Library/de-de</Folder>
<ViewAttributes Scope="Recursive" />
</QueryOptions></soap12:queryOptions>
<rowLimit><RowLimit></RowLimit></rowLimit>
<webID><WebID></WebID></webID>
</GetListItems>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I am always getting the folders from the root "Style Library"

Why????????

Here is a reference to another question which didn`t work for me:
[List getListItems WebService to return sub folder contents](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14496/list-getlistitems-webservice-to-return-sub-folder-contents/22169#22169)

The soap Request is taken to ASIHTTPRequest in an iPhone Application.

Comment: I am facing same problem. But, i didn't understand your answer. What is the difference between Style Library in line 3 and line 5 in your answer?Any help would be of great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So finally I figured it out!

The problem was that there was a namespace issue!

Instead of:

`<listName><ListName>Style Library</ListName></listName>`

I had to write:

`<ListName>Style Library</ListName>`

I still don't know why this was the issue but finally its solved.

It took the ListName right but everything after Listname wasnt taken at all.

Hope that this will help somebody with the same issue.