# SharePoint library web service

Tags: library, status

I have a SharePoint document library.

I need to access the file architecture in the library and also get the approval status for each file.

How can I get the information using SharePoint web service?

I tried to use `List.GetListItems` but it gave me the top level folders.

Answer (score 0):

You should either call the `GetListItems` method recursively for each subfolders, or even better, you should call this method using the

`<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /></QueryOptions>`

query option, that returns all items and subfolders. See a sample [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14496/list-getlistitems-webservice-to-return-sub-folder-contents).

If you need to perform the action from a web page via JavaScript, then I suggest you to use the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/548192) library.

Comment: yes, that is what I did, but it is very very slow even with paging of 30. Is there anyway to define a query to query only the subfolders/files for a particular folder?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You should specify the URL of the folder in the Folder
query option as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx
A sample for the syntax can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755673/get-file-folder-size-from-sharepoint-using-getlistitems